# java log4j.xml multiple appenders sharing a layout

Tags: java, configuration, log4j

Is there a way to configure a log4j.xml file to have multiple appenders share the same layout? I have copied the layout parameter into each of the appenders but it's a pain (and seems weird that I would need to do this) to update it in multiple places if the pattern changes.

thanks,
Jeff

Comment: How many appenders do you have? If you have so many that it's a pain to maintain them, you're likely going about things the wrong way.

Comment: Right now I have 2. A console appender and file appender. I just prefer the log messages to look the same in both and I have the same layout pattern for both. Seems like I should be able to consolidate...

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using log4j.properties instead of log4j.xml? The properties version accepts variable substitution for the values.

You can create your own properties inside the log4j.properties file (`someProp=value`) and later use `${someProp`} to get the value.

From what I remember (not sure though :D) you can also have this in the log4j.xml file but the variables must be defined as system variables (`-DsomeProp=value`) and in your log4j.xml you again use `${someProp}`. This version though is a little messy because you do not have the params declared in the same place you are using them, as you do in log4j.properties.

Comment: I'll give it a shot with log4j.properties. I think you're right that it does support the properties but for some reason I like the xml format better. Thanks.